# Error with one-to-one relationship entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-one

I have two classes

Cart

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Shop.Models
{
    public class Cart
    {
        public Cart()
        {
            this.Items = new HashSet<CartItem>();
        }

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ICollection<CartItem> Items { get; set; }


        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And Customer

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Shop.Models
{

    [Table("OrderCustomerInfo")]
    public partial class Customer
    {

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Нам важно знать как обращаться к вам")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Мы сожалеем, но нам сложно обращаться к вам с таким длинным именем")]
        public string AllName { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Нам необходим ваш номер телефона для связи с вами")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]*$")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Нам необходимо знать область и город доставки")]
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Название области и города слишком длинное, возможно вы ввели полный адресс не в то поле")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Нам необходимо знать адресс доставки")]
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Адресс слишком длинный, возможно вы ввели название города и области не в то поле")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string DeliveryType { get; set; }

        [StringLength(400, ErrorMessage = "Ваши пожелания слишком длинные, мы свяжемся с вами по телефону как только вы оформите заказ, и учтем ваши пожелания")]
        public string Additional { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool Processed { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool Complete { get; set; } 

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool Hidden { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }


        public int CartID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("CartID")]
        public virtual Cart Cart { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But when i tried, i got error

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Customer' on type 'Shop.Models.Cart' is not valid. The foreign key name 'CustomerId' was not found on the dependent type 'Shop.Models.Customer'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Comment: You can't have FK in both entities pointing to each other - it's a relation cycle. Decide which entity is the principal and which one is the dependent and keep the FK in dependent entity only. Or better setup [Shared Primary Key Association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations)

Comment: The `Customer` entity does not have a property named `CustomeId`. The primary key `ID` on `Customer` should be `CustomerId`. The `[ForeignKey("CustomerId")]` on `Cart` is looking for `CustomerId` as the `Key` on `Customer`